# How can I determine the velocity of a mass point in a resisting medium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How can I determine the velocity of a mass point if it doesn't have an initial velocity and it falls freely on  a vertical line
under the influence of the force of gravity in a resisting medium $\Phi = me^{v}$

Comment: What does $\Phi$ represent? Is it like a dissipation function?

Comment: Yes it is a dissipation function!